# I can't align horizontally the level tag's content and the input field

Tags: html, css, frontend, tailwind-ui

I am facing a problem where I can't align horizontally the level tag content and the input field in the same line.

[image]

I have used Tailwind CSS framework to build this website along with HTML5

I am sharing my code:

```
<!------------------ 
                    Calculation 
                ------------------->
                <div class="w-1/2 mx-auto">
                    <!-- Income & Expense -->

                    <!-- Income -->
                    <h4 class="text-lg font-semibold text-center mb-4">Income</h4>
                    <div class="w-1/2 mx-auto inline">
                        <label for="">Income:
                            <input type="text" class="border-2 bg-slate-200">
                        </label>

                    </div>


                    <!-- Expenses -->
                    <h4 class="text-lg font-semibold text-center mb-4 mt-4">Expenses</h4>


                    <div class="w-1/2 mx-auto mb-4">
                        <label for="">Food:
                            <input type="text" class="border-2 bg-slate-200">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-1/2 mx-auto mb-4">
                        <label for="">Rent:
                            <input type="text" class="border-2 bg-slate-200">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-1/2 mx-auto mb-4">
                        <label for="">Cloth:
                            <input type="text" class="border-2 bg-slate-200">
                        </label>
                    </div>


                    <!-- Calculate Button -->
                    <div class="w-1/2 mx-auto mt-5">
                        <button class="bg-sky-600 text-white font-medium px-10 py-2 rounded">Calculate</button>
                    </div>

                    <h4 class="text-lg font-semibold text-center mb-4 mt-4">Total Expenses: <span>00</span></h4>
                    <h4 class="text-lg font-semibold text-center mb-4 mt-4">Balance: <span>00</span></h4>
```